# Django ManyToMany alternative pros and cons

Tags: python, django

I was developing a chat system with channels and have this models for a thread *(some attributes removed for simplicity's sake)*:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User')
```

I realized it is also possible to implement it like this:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

class ThreadUsers(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using one over the other?

Comment: I would suggest using ManyToManyField. First of all, you would not have this middle layer. Second, It is suitable for your admin panel - you would have a specific UI for ManyToManyField, whereas for the bottom one you would need to have a separate page or inlines to add new records.

Comment: That's a good differentiation.

Comment: your "juction" model is basically what the `ManyToManyField` will do...

Answer (score 0):

All what you do - is the same. For your last example with custom M2M through model you can add M2M declaration `users` in Thread:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    # M2M declaration, which use your ThreadUsers
    users = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', through='ThreadUsers' )

class ThreadUsers(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Pros**:

- You create model self
- you can change behavior your M2M connection manually.
- You can add additional fields in M2M through connection.
- You have full control of this model.

**Cons**:

- problem with m2m connections in django admin.
- too much additional code, you can get a hard-to-find errors.
- some fields/widgets don't want to work with M2M.through.
- all was happened is your problem, this is not tested. Auto-through relation is tested in box.

we have in our projects 50/50 M2M-autothrough vs M2M-manualthrough. if I want to have more control on the models and realations - i use custom through.

p.s. in M2M-autothrough case Django created SomethingLikeYourThreadUsers Model and Table automatically.